# BASH script reading variable from another .txt file

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have output.txt file, where my script is storing some outputs, I just need to get the output of ID which is in the 1st line of the output.txt in myscript.sh file, can someone suggest a way to do that

```
{"id":"**dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf**","name":"new","url":"https://dev.azure.com/vishalmishra2424/82c93136-470c-4be0-b6da-a8234f49a695/_apis/git/repositories/dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf","project":{"id":"82c93136-470c-4be0-b6da-a8234f49a695","name":"vishalmishra","url":"https://dev.azure.com/vishalmishra2424/_apis/projects/82c93136-470c-4be0-b6da-a8234f49a695","state":"wellFormed","revision":12,"visibility":"public","lastUpdateTime":"2021-04-22T14:24:47.2Z"},"size":0,"remoteUrl":"https://vishalmishra2424@dev.azure.com/vishalmishra2424/vishalmishra/_git/new","sshUrl":"git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/vishalmishra2424/vishalmishra/new","webUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/vishalmishra2424/vishalmishra/_git/new","isDisabled":false}
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I searched few docs and tried the below one, but its not giving me what i am expecting

`while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ id ]] && declare "$line" && break
done < Repooutput.txt`

Comment: I suggest: `jq -r '.id' output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you posted looks like
[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and a utility named `file`
which can *guess* different types of file says that too:

```
$ file output.txt
output.txt: JSON data
```

You should use JSON-aware tools to extract value of `id`, for example
`jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.id' output.txt
**dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf**
```

or `jshon`:

```
$ jshon -e id < output.txt
"**dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf**"
```

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate your help

Comment: When I running this directly in shell, then its working fine. But when I am including it in script getting access denied. Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

`$ jq  -r '.id' Repooutput.txt
dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf`

Comment: `$ sh test.sh
test.sh: line 3: /c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/jq: Permission denied`

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. It might be Windows issue but I don't know how to use Windows, sorry.